# using handlebar template with moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, handlebars.js

I use moment and handlebar. I would like to use moment in handelbar.

I create a file with the content of this page
http://moment.handlebars.solidgoldpig.com/handlebars.moment.js.html

Git hub project
https://github.com/solidgoldpig/handlebars.moment

So the content of my handlebars.moment.js is http://pastebin.com/vhpg4SHA

In my code, i have

```
<script src="js/handlebars.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/handlebars.moment.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

In my template i have

```
{{moment birthdate "L"}}
```

I get the error

> Uncaught Error: Missing helper: "moment"

I don't use nodejs, is there a specific thing for nodejs? is there a way to use side on the client side without node js?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Moment helpers for Handlebars has some requirements of it's own:

1. A CommonJS or AMD module loader
2. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and moment (and of course Handlebars)

To solve these requirements, you are probably best off using a bundler such as [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). They bundle all your dependencies and your dependencies' dependencies without worrying about it yourself (too much) based on your application code.

Further, you need to register the `moment` helper with `Handlebars`, as shown in the code snippet on http://moment.handlebars.solidgoldpig.com/index.html, i.e.:

```
var Handlebars = require("handlebars");
var MomentHandler = require("handlebars.moment");
MomentHandler.registerHelpers(Handlebars);  // <- this is the important line
```

If you don't want to include a bundler, you need to include all dependencies manually and also make some adjustments to the module factory of the module you're trying to include.

Comment: i modifier the js file and that work. Only keep the register helpe of moment and all the map.

Comment: @nikc.org please can you help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654702/embed-moment-js-formatting-in-handlebars-templates