# embed moment.js formatting in handlebars templates

Tags: asp.net, handlebars.js, momentjs

I am trying get Moment.js date-time formating as part of my handlebars template.

**Actual Sample:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div id="hb-content"></div>

    <script id="hb-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <small>Last restarted:</small>
        <code>moment({{last_started}}).format('dddd, MMMM Do');</code>
        <code>moment({{last_started}}).format('h:mma');</code>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var temp = document.getElementById("hb-template").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(temp);
        var html = template({
            last_started: "/Date(1463152740000)/"
        })

        document.getElementById('hb-content').innerHTML = html;
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**Output:**

> Last restarted: moment(/Date(1463152740000)/).format('dddd, MMMM Do');
>   moment(/Date(1463152740000)/).format('h:mma');

**Expected Output:**

> Last restarted: Friday, May 13th 9:15pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it:**

```
<script id="hb-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <small>Last restarted:</small>
    <code>{{formatDate current_date 'dddd, MMMM Do'}}</code>
    <code>{{formatDate current_date 'h:mm:ssa'}}</code>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        Handlebars.registerHelper("formatDate", function (datetime, format) {
            return moment(datetime).format(format);
        });

        var temp = document.getElementById("hb-template").innerHTML;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(temp);
        var html = template({
            last_started: "/Date(1463152740000)/",
            current_date: new Date() //"/Date(1463152740000)/"
        })

        document.getElementById('hb-content').innerHTML = html;
    });
</script>
```